# How to perform search operation in ldap using spring

Tags: java, ldap, spring-ldap

I want to search specific user details from ldap. so i have wrote down following code retrieving user details but it returns list of user object. Basically i want only person obejct not list of person objects. for retreiving  i m using ldap template. How can i modify this code so that it return person object?

```
public void searchByFirstName(String loginId) {

        AndFilter filter = new AndFilter();
        filter.and(new EqualsFilter("objectclass", "Person"));
        filter.and(new EqualsFilter("cn", loginId));
        List list = ldapTemplate.search("", 
            filter.encode(),
            new AttributesMapper() {
                public Object mapFromAttributes(Attributes attrs) throws NamingException        {
                    return attrs.get("sn").get();
                }
            });


}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method you're calling, [ldapTemplate.search()](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ldap/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/core/LdapTemplate.html#search%28javax.naming.Name,%20java.lang.String,%20org.springframework.ldap.core.AttributesMapper%29) always returns a list of matching objects. This is because it is finding all the objects that match your criteria on the LDAP server. If you're not certain that a user matching your `loginId` exists, you are using the correct method already. Just check the length of the list and retrieve the first item from the returned list.

To get just a single item from LDAP, you need to know the *distinguished name* (DN) of a user in the LDAP server. A DN is a unique identifier of an object in LDAP, and you need to know this if you're going to look up a single object specifically. Depending on your LDAP configuration, this might be something like `cn=<loginId>,ou=users,dc=yourorg,dc=com`.

If you can construct the DN from the `loginId` you have, you can use the [ldapTemplate.lookup(String, AttributesMapper)](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ldap/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/core/LdapTemplate.html#lookup%28java.lang.String,%20org.springframework.ldap.core.AttributesMapper%29) method to find just a single object.